# Filter and unfilter with the same function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

I created a filter that filters data range by dates column with the criterion of today date.

I want to call the same button (with this function) to filter and unfilter the range back.

**I need when I press the button (call a function) one time - it filters.**

**I press it back - unfilters.**

Is it possible in some way?

```js
var sortRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 200, 6);

var filter = sortRange.createFilter()

var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateEqualTo(new Date())

filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria.build())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already built in -- you can query the [`Sheet` for the current filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getFilter()). If one is already set, then you can easily remove it. Otherwise, you will receive `null` and can create the [`BasicFilter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter) as required:

```
function foo() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  } else {
    /** create your filter */
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! It worked, thanks! So simple and elegant))

Answer (score 0):

Try something Like this:

```
function toFilterOrNotToFilter() {
  var onoff=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('on') || 'off';
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('on',(onoff=='on')?'off':'on');
  var sortRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 200, 6);
  if(onoff=='on') {
    //set filter
  }else{
    //don't set filter  
  }

}
```